# Windows form loads then quits

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I'm creating a checkout system for a supermarket. It consists of a checkout, server and MIS program an operates WCF services between them. The problem I have is that the checkout program, which is a windows form, does a few neccessaries in it's application_load method and then just quits.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CheckoutLibrary;
using Checkout.ServerLibraryService;
using Checkout.MarketService;

namespace Checkout
{
    public partial class theForm : Form
    {
        private static int checkoutID = 3;
        private Product[] allProducts;

        public theForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void theForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // First cache all products
            SupermarketServiceSoapClient marketService = new SupermarketServiceSoapClient();
            allProducts = marketService.GetAllProducts();
            // Load the service provided by the server
            ServiceClient serverService = new ServiceClient();
            // Load the event handlers for the bar code scanner
            BarcodeScanner scanner = new BarcodeScanner();
            scanner.ItemScanned += new BarcodeScanner.ItemScannedHandler(scanner_ItemScanned);
            scanner.AllItemsScanned += new BarcodeScanner.AllItemsScannedHandler(scanner_AllItemsScanned);
            scanner.Start(checkoutID);
        }

        void scanner_AllItemsScanned(EventArgs args)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void scanner_ItemScanned(ScanEventArgs args)
        {
            itemTextBox.Text = "Scanned " + GetItemName(args.Barcode);
        }

        private void scanItemButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            scanner_ItemScanned(new ScanEventArgs(GetRandBarcode()));
        }

        // A barcode -> product name look up method
        public string GetItemName(int barcode)
        {
            return allProducts[barcode].Description + " @ " + allProducts[barcode].Price;
        }

        // Method to grab a random barcode for simulation
        private int GetRandBarcode()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            return rand.Next(0,500);
        }
    }
}
```

And program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Checkout
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new theForm());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: can you show the code that opens theForm (show/showdialog)?

Comment: As in, the contents of program.cs?

Comment: Seeing your comments in @bugfixr answer it is no more necessary. It's clear that your form shows. So now try to put a breakpoint in the _scanner_AllItemsScanned_ event. Just to be sure that when your scanner start don't execute some of your events.

Comment: Do you have data bound controls on that form?

Answer (score 4):

In WinForms, if your form_load throws an exception, it quits without displaying anything. Annoying, but I'm guessing that's the problem.

You can try a `try/catch`, or you can hit `CTRL+ALT+E` and check the `Thrown Column` for `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` to see the error.

UPDATE:

Based on comments, here's a sample way to execute something on another thread.

```
ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(() => {
   try {
       scanner.Start(checkoutID);
   } catch {
       // Log error
   }
});
Thread t = new Thread(ts);
t.Start();
```

Comment: Ah, I did think of that but I was expecting an unhandled exception. I'll check this, thanks. I have a suspicion that it may be throwing an exception when trying to initialise one of the services.

Comment: Try-Catch didn't find any exceptions. In fact a breakpoint in the catch block wasn't triggered either. Hmm..

Comment: Does a breakpoint on the first line of code actually get hit? Any luck  checking the "Thrown" column in the CTRL+ALT+E (also found on the Debug/Exceptions menu)?

Comment: When I comment out the scanner.Start(x); call the form is fine. I'm assuming this must be called on a separate thread because at some point it closes the same thread the form is operating on?

Comment: It's hard to tell on my end what the scanner.Start is doing. If it's a blocking call though, you may want to wrap it in a Thread. I'll update my answer with the syntax you could try.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what the method is doing either, it's a library I was given and must use for the checkout.

Comment: Bah I thought this would work but it does the same thing. I must be missing something simple..

Comment: It still really feels like an exception is being thrown, though I'm not sure why your try/catch isn't getting it. You may want to move the BarCodeScanner stuff out to a temporary Button that you can click on after the form loads -- just to see if it indeed is throwing or causing a problem somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try moving it to a button, the try-catch still fails.